# Program output what & why?

Tags: c#

The output of this program is : 0 0

can any one please tell me why this kind of output is coming?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Sample
    {
        int i;
        Single j;
        public void SetData(int i, Single j)
        {
            i = i;
            j = j;
        }

        public void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + " " + j);
        }
    }

    class MyProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[ ] args)
        {
            Sample s1 = new Sample();
            s1.SetData(10, 5.4f);
            s1.Display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you execute this program once yourself? then please mention what output *you* observed. if you do not have visual-studio then see: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php Show us your output and then ask exactly what problem you have with that output.

Comment: Ok now that's just being lazy. We're not compilers... and surely, you can reason for yourself what the program does by following it line by line.

Comment: Agree with @Jayram. Run the program and see for yourself. To understand it, just put a breakpoint and debug. Visual Studio Express is free. Get it from here http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop

Comment: Please don't post questions on this site if you're not going to follow the rules for this site. Don't tell us off for making comments pointing out that *you're* not following the rules

Comment: Ok i executed this program & the output is :

0 0

can anyone tell me the reason why the output is 0 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 0, 0 as output because of in the `SetData` method, variables `i` and `j` are local variables to the method. And because of this your class level variables `i` and `j` are not getting assigned.

```
public void SetData(int i, Single j)
    {
        i = i;
        j = j;
    }
```

change the above code to:

```
public void SetData(int i, Single j)
    {
        this.i = i; // using this will refer to the class level variables 
        this.j = j;
    }
```

Or you could name the local variables differently, then the local variables will not hide the class level variables.

```
public void SetData(int a, Single b)
    {
        i = a;
        j = b;
    }
```

Now the output will be 10 and 5.4

Comment: If this answered your question, you should mark it as the answer. (You also get 2 reputation points.)

Answer (score 1):

The output of this program will be `0 0`. As in the method `SetData()`, you are assigning the value to the same variables, which are coming in that scope only. Hence the value is not assigned to the variables of the class. If you want to assign the values to the class variables, then just modify your `SetData()` method to

```
    public void SetData(int i, Single j)
    {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }
```

This will work.

I hope this explanation will help you. :)